# Python Threading/Request issue

Tags: python, multithreading, request

I have a multi-threading code in Python (firing several threads every second and closing them after), and it used to work fine. Recently, I added a new function (thread) for listening to a server for some tables (as they are streamed out from the server), through a Get Request (10 seconds timeout).

The issue is that the code works fine for about 1-2 hours and then I get the python thread error of **"error: can't start new thread"**, with having only ~20 active threads.

I tried having a singleton pool of thread and using it, but it did not help at all.

On a side note, removing this get request from the function resolves the issue and the code runs perfectly.

Please let me know your opinions,
Thank you.

```
def getStreamData(self):
    if (self.liveTablesTimer == None):
        self.startLiveTablesTimer()
        print("LiveTables timer started")
    self.voidTableCount += 1  # counting for connection refresh

    def separateThread():
        try:
            #return 0
            self.streamInConnection = requests.get(self.liveTablesUrl, stream=True, verify=False, timeout=10)
            #print("Live tables request sent as:", self.liveTablesUrl)
            if self.streamInConnection.encoding is None:
                self.streamInConnection.encoding = 'utf-8'

            for line in self.streamInConnection.iter_lines(decode_unicode=True):
                if line and self.userName != None:
                    #print("Raw stream received", line)
                    self.streamData.emit(line)
        except:
            print("getLiveTables stream link timeout")
            self.streamInConnection.close()
            if (self.voidTableCount>6*5):  #5 min
                try:
                    self.voidTableCount=0
                    pass
                except:
                    pass
        finally:
            return 0

    try:
        print("Starting thread for receiving liveTables data")
        #self.consCheck.threadExecutor.submit(separateThread)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=separateThread, args=[], daemon = True)
        thread.start()
    except Exception as err:
        print("liveTables stream error:", err)
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImN7F.png)

Comment: Is it really easy to take screenshot and post here rather then just doing copy/paste. Please provide code and error in text form! And have you read [tour] and [ask] please read these articles and edit your question accordingly!

Comment: This still lacks a [mcve] and the error in text form.

Answer (score 1):

Strangely, I removed the 'verify' parameter from the request and it resolved the issue.

```
requests.get(self.liveTablesUrl, stream=True, timeout=10)
```